# toggling css 'top' property position for chrome browser

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jquery-animate, toggle

I have a div(#aboutform) that is below the browser window and positioned originally as 'bottom'. Then when the #about div is clicked #aboutforms position is redefined to 'top' so that the div pops up from the bottom of the window.

What I am trying to do is to toggle this popup animation but I can't seem to redefine #aboutforms position to 'bottom' so that it returns to its original position.

I have tried removing the top property by using $(this).css('top', ''); but it will only work for a second before switching back to being defined by 'top.'

CSS

```
#aboutform{
background-color: white;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
z-index: 4;
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 1150px;
bottom: -1150px;
border-top:2px solid black;
}
```

jQuery

```
            $('#og').click(function() { $(this).data('clicked', true); });

            $('#about').click(function() {
                var aboutFormTop = 85;
                if ($('#og').data('clicked')) {
                    var $this = $("#aboutform");
                        $this.css("top", $this.position().top);

                    $("#aboutform").animate({ 'top': aboutFormTop }, 1000)
                    $("#og").animate({'bottom': '-=-65px'}, 100)
                }
```

2nd half which I am troubleshooting

```
                //redefines #aboutform's position to 'top' for chrome browser
                var $this = $("#aboutform");
                    $this.css("top", $this.position().top);

                        $("#aboutform").toggle(function() {
                                $(this).animate({ 'top': aboutFormTop }, 1000);
                        }, function() {         
                                    //redefines #aboutform's position to 'bottom'
                                    //for chrome browser but only for a second 
                                    //('top' position becomes dominant)         
                                    var $this = $("#aboutform");
                                    $this.css("bottom", $this.position().bottom);
                                    $(this).css('top', '');
                                    $(this).animate({ 'bottom': -1150 }, 1000);
                        });

            });
```

edited code and solution

```
        $('#og').click(function() { $(this).data('clicked', true); });

            $('#about').click(function() {
                var aboutFormTop = 85;
                if ($('#og').data('clicked')) {
                    //$("#nav").animate({'bottom': '-=77px'}, 100);
                    var $this = $("#aboutform");
                            $this.css("top", $this.position().top);
                            $(this).animate({"top": 0}, 1000); 
                    $("#aboutform").animate({ 'top': aboutFormTop }, 1000)
                    $("#og").animate({'bottom': '-=-65px'}, 100)
                }
            //redefines #aboutform's position to 'top' for chrome browser
            var $this = $("#aboutform");
                $this.css("top", $this.position().top);
                $(this).animate({ 'top': 0 }, 1000);
            $("#aboutform").animate({ 'top': aboutFormTop }, 1000);
            $("#aboutform").css('bottom', 'auto');

            $("#minleft").click(function(){
                                $("#aboutform").css('top', 'auto');
                                $("#aboutform").animate({ 'bottom': -1150 }, 1000);
                    });
        });
```

Comment: You are still maintaining bottom as -1150px when setting the top. Set it to 0 or auto and see if it works.

Comment: I tried your suggestion with the same result.

Comment: Thanks @GaneshPandhere. Got it to work with your and Shashank's suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('this').css('top', 'auto');

//or remove style attribute and write new css..
$(this).removeAttr("style");
```

//new css

Comment: remove the style attr completly and write new css
or u can remove and add new css classes based on events..

Comment: Thanks @Shashank. Got it to work with your and GaneshPandhere's suggestions.